# How to import private key in web3.py

Tags: blockchain, ether, etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3.py

I have the requirement to convert my private key to address and please don't devote me I have searched already I come to across many solution but all are outdate  [example](https://www.arthurkoziel.com/generating-ethereum-addresses-in-python/) and really many more but it seem they are all outdated the packages of python which they are using is not getting installed on my packages one is pyetshah if I am not  mistaken the name I have did the same task on javascript but now I need to do it using python. I can install web3 module but I have not get any method to convert private key to address one solution also available for ethereum module of python but it does not install properly.

Comment: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#read-a-private-key-from-an-environment-variable

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
account = web3.eth.Account.privateKeyToAccount(your_private_key)

print(account.address)
# Prints the public key
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Brownie framework to do that. Brownie allows you to add your private key to its accounts storage and from the private key, it can easily obtain your address (public key) whenever you want to work on a contract.

You can run

```
pip install eth-brownie
```

To get started.